# Make the JavaScript function show the result rather than hide what the result isn't

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have found this code through W3Schools and I have changed it to my liking for my school project. Currently, it is a dropdown that when typed into removes the results that aren't spelt the same. What I'm looking to do is reverse this where they all start hidden and when the result is typed in it will show, many thanks!

```js
function searchFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("illnessSearch");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("illnessList");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  // Via: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_search_menu.asp
}
```

```css
#illnessSearch {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#illnessList {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#illnessList li a {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#illnessList li a:hover {
  background-color: #666666;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <br class="a">
  <center>
    <input type="text" id="illnessSearch" onkeyup="searchFunction()" placeholder="&#128269; | Illness 
        name...">

    <ul id="illnessList" class="dropdown-content">
      <li><a href="coronavirus.php">CORONAVIRUS</a></li>
      <li><a href="hay-fever.php">HAY FEVER</a></li>
      <li><a href="influenza-adult.php">INFLUENZA (ADULT)</a></li>
      <li><a href="influenza-child.php">INFLUENZA (CHILD)</a></li>
      <li><a href="lyme-disease.php">LYME DISEASE</a></li>
    </ul>
  </center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically had it, all you need to do is hide the elements by default. Because your JavaScript is referencing the `li`, I had to add a style for the `li` to hide it by default. Once the user begins typing, it will show. I also added a check to hide all results when the text box is empty.

```js
function searchFunction() {
    // Declare variables
    var empty = false;
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("illnessSearch");
    if(input.value.length < 1){
      empty = true;
    }
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("illnessList");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

    // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 && !empty) {
            li[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    // Via: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_search_menu.asp
}
```

```css
#illnessSearch {
      width: 50%;
      font-size: 20px;
      padding: 20px;
      font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#illnessList {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
}
#illnessList li {
display: none;
}
#illnessList li a {
      width: 50%;
      padding: 20px;
      font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
      display: block;
}

#illnessList li a:hover {
      background-color: #666666;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <br class="a">
    <center>
    <input type="text" id="illnessSearch" onkeyup="searchFunction()" placeholder="&#128269; | Illness 
    name...">

    <ul id="illnessList" class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="coronavirus.php">CORONAVIRUS</a></li>
        <li><a href="hay-fever.php">HAY FEVER</a></li>
        <li><a href="influenza-adult.php">INFLUENZA (ADULT)</a></li>
        <li><a href="influenza-child.php">INFLUENZA (CHILD)</a></li>
        <li><a href="lyme-disease.php">LYME DISEASE</a></li>
    </ul>
    </center>
</div>
```